# ZenTest errors preventing autotest from running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autotest, zentest

I've previously added ZenTest to my gemfile to get autotest to run.  On this occasion I get the following error four times over:

```
saasbook@saasbook:~/Documents/github/LocalSupport$ bundle exec autotest
Invalid gemspec in [/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/specifications/ZenTest-4.9.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["< 2.1, >= 1.8"]
```

I've searched on this error and found a number of discussions in the github repo for ZenTest:

https://github.com/seattlerb/zentest/issues/29
https://github.com/seattlerb/zentest/issues/32
https://github.com/seattlerb/zentest/issues/33

I've followed some of the advice there, uninstalled and re-installing ZenTest, but no joy.  I'm on ubuntu running ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]

My entire app is available here:

https://github.com/tansaku/LocalSupport

so for example you can check out my GemFile:

https://github.com/tansaku/LocalSupport/blob/master/Gemfile

Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I am seing the same thing. Did you report this?

Comment: I saw it reported and closed within older issues as linked to above - wasn't sure how to report it effectively ...

Comment: @maasha I notice there is an issue on github now: https://github.com/seattlerb/zentest/issues/40

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just fixed this by editing

/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/specifications/ZenTest-4.9.0.gemspec

so that the line specifying the rubygems version is now this:

```
 s.required_rubygems_version = Gem::Requirement.new("< 2.1") if s.respond_to? :required_rubygems_version=
```

now everything runs fine ...

Comment: a more stable fix appears to be:  "upgrade rubygems, uninstall zentest and reinstall zentest." seems to have worked for me on at least one system

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading rubygems and reinstalling the ZenTest (according to what Sam wrote) solved my problem but it causes me another problem:

```
/Users/neo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:187:in `stub_source_index170': uninitialized constant Gem::SourceIndex (NameError)
```

Anything I want to do, from running the autotest to starting rails server, it gives me that error. After searching a bit I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079182/cant-run-rails-server-after-accidentally-running-gem-update-system) page.
It seems that the latest version of rubygems has some bugs, so you should not upgrade it to the latest version, instead upgrade it to a stabler version like 1.8.24 .