# Can't run rails server after accidentally running $ gem update --system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm

I ran `gem update --system` thinking it would solve a problem I was having, and now I can't run `rails server`. It won't load and instead, I keep getting the following. Can someone tell me how to undo this and revert back to before I ran the update?

I've already ran `git checkout`, but the problem persists...

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:187:in `stub_source_index170': uninitialized constant Gem::SourceIndex (NameError)
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:353:in `stub_rubygems'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:250:in `replace_entrypoints'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:14:in `setup'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.0.7/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:66:in `setup'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.0.7/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:78:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `rescue in require'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:35:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:9:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Do you need to upgrade bundler?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Seems like the latest version of Rubygems is buggy.

You just have to revert back to an older version with the following command and everything should work fine :

```
gem update --system 1.8.24
```

Comment: Rather than downgrading rubygems, i think it's a better idea to update bundler per the other answer :)

Comment: I agree, that's why I up-voted the other answer! Should I edit mine as well?

Comment: @DanielRistic, Doesn't matter. I tried bruno's first but didn't work out in my case. Yours worked like a charm. Upvoting both the answers and the question.

Answer (score 38):

I had the same issue today. Updating bundler to the latest version fixed the problem:

```
gem update bundler
```

And if you are running rbenv

```
rbenv rehash
```

Comment: This worked for me after seeing a similar error when trying to coax RubyMine to debug a ruby script (error like: stub_source_index170': uninitialized constant Gem::SourceIndex (NameError)). Just gem update bundler fixed it.